# Error installing PyGObject: preprocessor command 'mesondefine' not valid

Tags: python, c

I'm working on a Python project which make use of GLib and other GObject-based libraries. The fact is I'm working on Windows 10 and the only official way to use these libraries is to install *MSYS2 - MinGW*, as suggested by the official wiki; it works, but it's not what I need: what I'm looking for is a way to use these libraries directly into my work in order to remove all the "moduleNotFound" errors that are keeping poping up while debugging. That's why I'm trying to intall the PyGObject module with pip directly.

This is where the pain started: I've tried installing PyGObject by simply typing

```
pip install PyGObject
```

in the command prompt, but the installation failed due to the lack of several header files. I've already solved this issue (or I think I had), but now I'm stucked again. The point is that 1 of these files (or more than 1, I don't know how many are) uses a preprocessor directive, **#mesondefine**, which is not recognized by the Visual Studio 2019 built-in C/C++ preprocessor (cl.exe).
This is the output of the last attempt:

```
C:\Users\[myUserName]>pip install PyGObject
Collecting PyGObject
  Using cached PyGObject-3.38.0.tar.gz (712 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... done
Collecting pycairo>=1.11.1
  Using cached pycairo-1.20.0-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl (1.2 MB)
Building wheels for collected packages: PyGObject
  Building wheel for PyGObject (PEP 517) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'd:\python\python.exe' 'd:\python\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' build_wheel 'C:\Users\[myUserName]\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp0j7ig_7s'
       cwd: C:\Users\[myUserName]\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-tbfr9hx_\pygobject
  Complete output (48 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pygtkcompat
  copying pygtkcompat\generictreemodel.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pygtkcompat
  copying pygtkcompat\pygtkcompat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pygtkcompat
  copying pygtkcompat\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pygtkcompat
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\gi
  copying gi\docstring.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\gi
  copying gi\importer.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\gi
  copying gi\module.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\gi
  copying gi\pygtkcompat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\gi
  copying gi\types.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\gi
  copying gi\_constants.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\gi
  copying gi\_error.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\gi
  copying gi\_gtktemplate.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\gi
  copying gi\_option.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\gi
  copying gi\_ossighelper.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\gi
  copying gi\_propertyhelper.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\gi
  copying gi\_signalhelper.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\gi
  copying gi\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\gi
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\gi\repository
  copying gi\repository\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\gi\repository
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\gi\overrides
  copying gi\overrides\Gdk.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\gi\overrides
  copying gi\overrides\GdkPixbuf.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\gi\overrides
  copying gi\overrides\GIMarshallingTests.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\gi\overrides
  copying gi\overrides\Gio.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\gi\overrides
  copying gi\overrides\GLib.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\gi\overrides
  copying gi\overrides\GObject.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\gi\overrides
  copying gi\overrides\Gtk.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\gi\overrides
  copying gi\overrides\keysyms.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\gi\overrides
  copying gi\overrides\Pango.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\gi\overrides
  copying gi\overrides\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\gi\overrides
  running build_ext
  pycairo: new API
  pycairo: trying include directory: 'C:\\Users\\[myUserName]\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-env-zsho8tor\\overlay\\Lib\\site-packages\\cairo\\include'
  pycairo: found 'C:\\Users\\[myUserName]\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-env-zsho8tor\\overlay\\Lib\\site-packages\\cairo\\include\\py3cairo.h'
  building 'gi._gi' extension
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\gi
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DPY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN -IC:\Users\[myUserName]\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-tbfr9hx_\pygobject -IC:\Users\[myUserName]\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-tbfr9hx_\pygobject\gi -Id:\python\include -Id:\python\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tcgi\gimodule.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\gi\gimodule.obj -FImsvc_recommended_pragmas.h
  gimodule.c
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\ATLMFC\include\glibconfig.h(13): fatal error C1021: preprocessor command 'mesondefine' not valid
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.27.29110\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for PyGObject
Failed to build PyGObject
ERROR: Could not build wheels for PyGObject which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

So here is my question: there is a way to manually update my C/C++ preprocessor with new directives? If yes, what should I do in my case? (I'm using Visual Studio 2019 - Community Edition)

P.S.: If you need more information, just ask me in the comment section below.

Comment: I doubt you can easily for any compiler. I expect you were supposed to pre-process your code with [Meson](https://mesonbuild.com/) before building it?

Comment: It looks like you just copied header files from the source distribution instead of properly installing GLib. Also: never touch your system directories, store your stuff somewhere else.